Bringing satellite-capable iPhones into India
It seems India prohibits satellite phones for security reasons, but would this apply to personal phones like iPhone 14 and later which uses satellites for its emergency SOS feature (https://support.apple.com/en-us/101573)? Apple says its areas of coverage do not include India but is this good enough for legal purposes?
I've heard of travelers being arrested in India for having Garmin satellite devices without permission but not iPhones so I would assume the latter is okay.
(Tangential question: If you are just transiting through an Indian airport, is it okay to bring any Garmin satellite device in your carry-on?)

Apple maybe trying to get access to India anyway.

The exact same model (e.g. iPhone 16 Pro Max, model number A3296) is sold in the EU or India (there are other model numbers for a number of other countries, including the US). It would thus be difficult for them to have a problem with a phone which is readily available in India.
Some models (sold in China and a small number of other countries) do not have the satellite functionality at all, but that is not the case for India.
Most of the satellite functionality (SOS, roadside assistance) only works in covered countries.
SMS via satellite is more likely to depend on your home wireless provider, no idea if they will shut it down when in India. There are a number of other features which are automatically enabled/disabled based on location (like the mandatory camera click in Japan or Korea), so I guess that if there are any regulatory issues Apple would do the same in India.

Your first paragraph about the iPhone model is not necessarily correct.  Apple can and does enable/disable features based on region.  See here  but I can't see anything obvious about satellite SMS messaging (or I'm just blind)

@PeterM as stated in the last paragraph, they do often enable or disable features based on where you are (or sometimes other parameters such as language, carrier, etc.), but the phone itself is exactly the same between the EU and India.

I think it depends on feature. For the camera shutter sound, the Japan-sold iPhone will make camera shutter sounds, but I think the software turns the sound off if traveling outside of Japan (idk if it's based on connecting to a foreign carrier or based on GPS). But other variants have hardware differences, like the China-sold iPhone which has different modem bands as well as lack of eSIM and instead still have a physical dual SIM tray.
